# How to set periodType to quarter

Tags: collection, grid

In admin for grids there is filter named Period which has 3 possible values:; day, month and year. I would like to add an extra option called quarter which will give results for each 3 months.The function which needs to be edited is the following from my custom collection

```
    protected function _getPeriodFormat()
{
    $adapter = $this->getConnection();
    if ('month' == $this->_periodType) {
        $periodFormat = $adapter->getDateFormatSql('i.created_at', '%Y-%m');
    } else if ('year' == $this->_periodType) {
        $periodFormat = $adapter->getDateExtractSql('i.created_at', Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface::INTERVAL_YEAR);
    } else if ('quarter' == $this->_periodType) {
        $periodFormat = $adapter->getDateExtractSql('i.created_at', what should be here);
    } else {
        $periodFormat = $adapter->getDateFormatSql('i.created_at', '%Y-%m-%d');
    }

    return $periodFormat;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could go with `Zend_Db_Expr('(month(i.created_at) % 3) + 1')`

```
$periodFormat = new Zend_Db_Expr('(MONTH(i.created_at) % 3) + 1');
```